# How to change frames when i move my mouse left or right (actionscript)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I am using a fish as a mouse cursor but when i move it around my stage it only faces one direction. what I want it to do is change direction when i move it left or right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should allow you to control the timeline of the fish movieclip:

It works by listening for a change in the position of the mouse, which after detecting the speed in which it does this, moves the timeline of the desired `movieclip` forwards or backwards depending on the new direction of the mouse.

Taken from the following thread: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1450102?tstart=0

```
var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(this);  // <- The timeline you want to control with mouse position
var maxScrollSpeed:int=100;  // max fps for mc above
var m:Number;
var b:Number;
var prevFPS:int;

paramF(0,-maxScrollSpeed,stage.stageWidth,maxScrollSpeed);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,scrollF);

function scrollF(e:Event):void
{
    var fps:int = Math.round(m*mouseX+b);
    if(prevFPS&&prevFPS!=fps)
    {
        if(fps!=0)
        {
            if(fps>0)
            {
                playF(mc,mc.currentFrame,mc.totalFrames,fps);
            } 
            else 
            {
                playF(mc,mc.currentFrame,1,-fps);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            stopF(mc);
        }
    }
    prevFPS=fps;
}

function playF(mc:MovieClip, m:int, n:int, fps:int):void 
{
    var playFFF2:Function = function(mc:MovieClip):void 
    {
        if (mc.m<mc.n) 
        {
            mc.nextFrame();
        } 
        else 
        {
            mc.prevFrame();
        }
        if (mc.currentFrame == mc.n) 
        {
            clearInterval(mc.int);
        }
        //updateAfterEvent();
    };
    mc.m = m;
    mc.n = n;
    mc.fps = fps;
    mc.gotoAndStop(mc.m);
    clearInterval(mc.int);
    mc.int = setInterval(playFFF2, 1000/mc.fps, mc);
}
function stopF(mc:MovieClip):void 
{
    clearInterval(mc.int);
}

function paramF(x1:Number,y1:Number,x2:Number,y2:Number):void
{
    m=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
    b=y1-m*x1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the `mouseX` position in a variable. When the mouse moves, compare the new `mouseX` position with your stored variable (you can do this with the `ENTER_FRAME` or `MOUSE_MOVE` events). If the new position is greater than the previous position, set the `scaleX` to 1, if the new position is less than the previous position set the `scaleX` to -1 (or vice versa).
Update the stored value and repeat.

Comment: how can i make above work with this code snippet " /* Custom Mouse Cursor
Replaces the default mouse cursor with the specified symbol instance.
*/

stage.addChild(Gfish);
Gfish.mouseEnabled = false;
Gfish.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_CustomMouseCursor_3);

function fl_CustomMouseCursor_3(event:Event)
{
 Gfish.x = stage.mouseX;
 Gfish.y = stage.mouseY;
}
Mouse.hide();

//To restore the default mouse pointer, uncomment the following lines:
//Gfish.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_CustomMouseCursor_3);
//stage.removeChild(Gfish);
//Mouse.show();
"